# Does Kivy work better on a specific Python version?

Tags: python, kivy

Just starting with Kivy. I'm planning to develop mobile apps using Kivy under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Before installing, I want to know if there's a specific version of Python (2 or 3) where Kivy runs better. For example, the [Kivy docs](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer) say I need to add a different Pygame PPA before installing Kivy if I want to use Python 3 and warn:

```
** These Pygame packages are neither provided nor supported by the Kivy project. **
```

I don't like that very much.

I wish to use Python 3, but I don't want to be in some trouble later because of version-compatibility stuff. Does anybody experimented problems with Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use Python 2. Your code can likely be modified into Python 3 using the 2to3 tool or similar at a later time. But as you read, there are some compatibility issues with some libraries when using Python 3. Also, packaging is far more solid with Python 2 - you can't build for Android (or iOS I believe) with Python 3, nor can you use pyinstaller to make a Windows executable.

Comment: Can't build for Android using Python 3!? I have no doubt now so. Thanks for the answer!